# How to create a custom Adminhtml controller

Tags: controllers, routing

I'm just trying to create a simple adminhtml controller.

```
#config.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <AD_CustomShipping>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </AD_CustomShipping>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <AD_CustomShipping>
            <class>AD_CustomShipping_Block</class>
        </AD_CustomShipping>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <AD_CustomShipping>
            <class>AD_CustomShipping_Helper</class>
        </AD_CustomShipping>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <AD_CustomShipping after="Mage_Adminhtml">AD_CustomShipping</AD_CustomShipping>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

This is the controller:

```
#app/code/local/AD/CustomShipping/controllers/CustomShippingController.php
 /**
 * Class AD_Customshipping_CustomShippingController
 */
 class AD_CustomShipping_CustomShippingController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {
    /**
     * Return some checking result
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function checkAction()
     {
         $result = 1;
         Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody( $result );
     }
}
```

When I try to reach the URL `https://example.com/adminpanel/customshipping/check/key/6df9ce54d9c315cbdf9484dc54dfcd678/` it shows me 404 Error.

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I solved the problem.

I have to have the `CustomshippingController.php` in the `/app/code/local/AD/CustomShipping/controllers/` folder

And the correct URL is:

`https://example.com/index.php/adminpanel/customshipping/check/...`

Answer (score 2):

It took me ages to figure out that

`<args>
    <modules>
        <myrandomtag before="Mage_Adminhtml">
            My_Module_Adminhtml
        </myrandomtag>
    </modules>
</args>`

IS NOT SAME AS

`<args>
    <modules>
        <myrandomtag before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Module_Adminhtml</myrandomtag>
    </modules>
</args>`

So there should be no space or new line inside your random tag

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Thank dog for Xdebug and Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

Answer (score 0):

As you have using new new system

```
 <AD_CustomShipping after="Mage_Adminhtml">AD_CustomShipping</AD_CustomShipping>
            </modules>
```

create admin controller so.

`CustomShippingController.php`  location `app/code/local/AD/CustomShipping/controllers/` should be

```
app/code/local/AD/CustomShipping/controllers/Adminhtml/
```

and you can access this by

**https://example.com/admin/customShipping/check.....**

Comment: I created the Adminhtml folder and moved the controller file into there. And renamed the controller's class name. Still doesn't work.. Please note that I use the URL http://example.com/adminpanel/... not http://example.com/admin/..., because the admin panel URL prefix is changed in the system configuration.